# replace string with PHP code

Tags: php, string, plugins, joomla, replace

I need to find a string within a string ("foo", for example) and then replace it with a PHP code. Is it possible?

I'm creating a Joomla Plugin. When my article has something like "{foo}", i will replace it with an include (require, or whatever).

I've made something like:

```
public function onContentBeforeDisplay($context, &$row, &$params, $page=0)
    {
        // $row->text has the article text ...
        if (preg_match('/{contact-form}/', $row->text))
        {
            require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'tmpl' . DS . 'default.php');
        }
    }
```

But this code will insert default.php at the beginning. I want to replace it in {contact-form} tag.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please explain the context of your problem and provide an example?

Comment: Have you tried [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace)?

Comment: @deceze the question was tagged with str-replace, you'd almost *assume* the OP checked the docs first... wouldn't you? ;-)

Comment: str_replace adds the code without evalute it.

Comment: @rich Good point. :o) @thom Why don't you run the code first and replace `{foo}` with the result of the run code?

Comment: Can't you use Joomla's default plugin system? You basically just need to provide your hook and what you want to do when the system finds it

Comment: My plugin gets Joomla's article text, then I need to search for the tag {foo}, and then add a form there... If i use str_replace I can't have code like if ($_POST): // insert at database ...

Comment: @Damien Pirsy, any URL about it? Thank you

Comment: @thom check their [API] (http://api.joomla.org/) reference. I think their wiki section is not updated to the latest releases (not only 1.6, but even 15)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function "`substr_replace()`", whose details are [given here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php).
    \n";

```
/* These two examples replace all of $var with 'bob'. */
echo substr_replace($var, 'bob', 0) . "<br />\n";
echo substr_replace($var, 'bob', 0, strlen($var)) . "<br />\n";

/* Insert 'bob' right at the beginning of $var. */
echo substr_replace($var, 'bob', 0, 0) . "<br />\n";

/**
 * Your food & search is here
 */
/* These next two replace 'MNRPQR' in $var with 'bob'. */
echo substr_replace($var, 'bob', 10, -1) . "<br />\n";
echo substr_replace($var, 'bob', -7, -1) . "<br />\n";

/* Delete 'MNRPQR' from $var. */
echo substr_replace($var, '', 10, -1) . "<br />\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PHP file that matches the keyword (like: foo.php) and simply extract the keyword from the text and use it to include that file.

For example:

```
<?php
$str = "This is {foo} text";
$includePath = "/path/to/my/files/";

// Careful with the Regular Expression. If you allow chars like . in the
// keyword this could create a security problem. (Dots allow you to go backwards
// which would allow people to execute files outside your path.)
if (preg_match_all('/\{([\w]+)\}/', $str, $matches))
{
    foreach ($matches[1] as $_match)
    {
        $filePath = $includePath . $_match . ".php";
        if (file_exists($filePath))
        {
            include $filePath;
        }
        else
        {
            trigger_error("File does not exist '$filePath'.", E_USER_WARNING);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want this, don't you?

```
<?php

$replacement = file_get_contents('myfile.php');

$content = str_replace('{foo}', eval($replacement), $content);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace any string on series of files on your remote server and well you don't have time for it! , here is your solution , I hope it can help someone.

```
 ////
 //PHP 5.3 + Class find and replace string in files
 //
 //by Bruce Afruz 
 //
 //2013
 //
 //example usage for single file:
 //
 //$new = new fileReplacement('./');
 //$new->setExt("check.php");
 //$new->changeContents("hello", "goodbye");
 //
 //example usage for multiple files:
 //
 //$new = new fileReplacement('./test');
 //$new->setExt("*.html");
 //$new->changeContents("hello", "goodbye");
 //
 //to change directory:
 //
 //$new = new fileReplacement('./test');
 //$new->setDir("./test2");
 //$new->setExt("*.html");
 //$new->changeContents("hello", "goodbye");
 ////


 class fileReplacement 
 {
  private $ext , $dir ;
  public function getDir() {
   return $this->dir;
  }
  public function setDir($dir) {
   $this->dir = $dir;
  }
   public function getExt() {
   return $this->ext;
  }
  public function setExt($ext) {
   $this->ext = $ext;
  }
 function __construct($dir) {
   $this->dir = $dir;
  }

  public function rglob($pattern = '*', $flags = 0, $path = '') {

  chdir($this->getDir());
  $paths = glob($path . '*', GLOB_MARK | GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT);
  $files = glob($path . $pattern, $flags);
  foreach ($paths as $path) {
  $files = array_merge($files, $this->rglob($pattern, $flags, $path));
  }
  return $files;
 }

 public function changeContents($replace , $sentence , $flags = 0, $path = '') {
 $all = $this->rglob($this->getExt() , $flags, $path);
 foreach ($all as $file) {

  $filename = $file;
  $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
  $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
  fclose($handle);
  $contents = str_replace($replace , $sentence, $contents);

  if (is_writable($filename)) {
   if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+')) {
    echo "Cannot open file ($filename)
";
    exit;
   }

   // Write $contents to our opened file.
   if (fwrite($handle, $contents) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)
";
    exit;
   }

   echo "Success, wrote content to file ($filename)
";

   fclose($handle);
  } else {
   echo "The file $filename is not writable
";
  }
 }
 }}
```